# How to read the GUID Partition Table (GPT) and its entries?

Tags: c, disk-partitioning, guid-partition-table

To read the MBR partition table we use an offset of `0x1be`, similarly what is the offset for reading the GP(artition)T(able) entries (ie, number of partitions and their sizes).

I am writing a C program using "gdisk" to create the partitions, I need to write the filesystems onto these partitions. So for this I need to read the GPT header to get the number of partitions and their allocated sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the offset for reading the GPT partition table entries

It typically is located in [LBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_block_addressing) 2. To verify check offset 0x30 (base-10 offset 48) to the [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_table_header_.28LBA_1.29).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I get value "2" present at 0x48. i dont know if iam doing the correct thing. Using Sector = 1 offset = 0x48.

Comment: `2` means LBA 2. So this should be cylinder 0, head 0, sector 2, offset 0 for the GPT entries. Please see the links in my answer.

Comment: Sector 2 and offset = 0 works. I need one more clarification. Can we use "gdisk" to create partitions of morethan 2.2TB ?

Comment: I need one more clarification. Can we use "gdisk" to create partitions of morethan 2.2TB ?

Comment: @swapneelmashalkar: This would suit well as another question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103107/can-we-use-gdisk-to-create-partitions-of-morethan-2-2tb